Degrees of Freedom in Emmeans
I am using the 'emmeans' package in R to compute estimated marginal means for my (liner mixed-effects) model. However, I am enountering a warning message related to the number of observations exceeding 3000. Here is the specific code and the warning message I am receiving:
emmeans_results <- emmeans(lmer_model, ~ intervention + group)
The Warning Message is:
Note: D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000. To enable adjustments, add the argument 'pbkrtest.limit = 161345' (or larger) [or, globally, 'set emm_options(pbkrtest.limit = 161345)' or larger]; but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use. Note: D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000. To enable adjustments, add the argument 'lmerTest.limit = 161345' (or larger) [or, globally, 'set emm_options(lmerTest.limit = 161345)' or larger]; but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use.
How can I handle this issue without running into significant computation time and memory use (setting lmerTest.limit = 161345 causes the R to crash on my computer). Is there a recommended approach for dealing with this in 'emmeans'?

I would recommend you add a phrase asking about how transforming the estimate to marginal means affects df's in general. Most answers will address your issue anyway, but it avoids the question being shut down for being too focused on one programming package.

There really isn't much you can do about this other than specifying mode = "asymp" (infinite d.f.) or explicity setting df = <some value>. For the latter, perhaps use df equal to the smallest group size minus 1.
